# How can I create in MAUI Android a thumbnail from a byte array?

Tags: maui, thumbnails

MAUI. I have read (from a database) a byte array named "receiptDocumentBytes".

I want to create a thumbnail of this image, and only pass that thumbnail among my various objects in the application (the images themselves would be quite large).

So once I have my receiptDocumentBytes byteArray I have tried to do this:

```
if (receiptDocumentBytes != null)
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(receiptDocumentBytes))
#if ANDROID
            image = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform.PlatformImage.FromStream(ms);
#else
            image = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Win2D.W2DImage.FromStream(stream);
#endif

        //Create the thumbnail of this image:
        using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(receiptDocumentBytes))
            {
                if (image != null)
                    {
                        int thumbnailSize = Preferences.Get("ThumbnailSize", 600);
                        //The largest dimension will be set to 'thumbnailSize' pixels while maintaining the aspect ratio:
                        IImage thumbnailImage = image.Downsize(thumbnailSize, true);
                        using (MemoryStream memStream = new())
                            {
                                thumbnailImage.Save(memStream);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

How does this behave ? Oddly.

My MemoryStream ms (the first using) is populated (it has a length, a capacity, etc), but the image object

```
image = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform.PlatformImage.FromStream(ms);
```

is not - it shows Height and Width = System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, all the other properties being null.

However, the object itself is not null, thus passing the test

```
if (image != null)
```

Then, on the line

```
IImage thumbnailImage = image.Downsize(thumbnailSize, true);
```

the execution does not show any exception, but jumps to the end of my

```
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(receiptDocumentBytes))
```

So the code does not execute, is not caught by my error handling, and it does not create any thumbnail image.

So.... what am I doing wrong here, please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What image format is receiptDocumentBytes?

Comment: Hi. Jason. It could be any image format, I assume. This is supposed to represent exactly this - an expense receipt. So I assume it could be any image format - jpg, or bmp... - I don't know. I get those via a webservice, from a database.  But, Jason,.... does it matter ?

Comment: Yes it does.  If you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.graphics.platform.platformimage.fromstream?view=net-maui-7.0) it says that the default image is PNG.  If it’s not a png you’ll need to specify the image type

Comment: Okay. So let's assume this was a *.png. In that case, my code above should work ? Or is it still incorrect (as I assume) ? Anyway, I will try with a png right away.

Comment: It behaves exactly the same, Jason. I assume there's something wrong with my code, but not just the file extension :-(

Comment: `thumbnailSize` should be a `float`.  You might also try using `false` for the 2nd argument

Comment: Have you considered https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp/? It's a cross-platform 2D graphics API based on Google's Skia Graphics Library owned by Microsoft. It would have no problem with handling your requirements: loading an image format from a memory stream, downsampling, and exporting into a new memory stream.

Comment: Hi, Jason. Unfortunately I have made no progress on this one. No matter how I pass the parameters to Image.Downsize(), the result is the same exception (and behavior).